# Salesforce.com login page not accessible from java code from with in a proxy

Tags: rest, salesforce, httpclient, force.com

I am new to salesforce.com platform. I am trying to execute the demo application given at `http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API`. The sample application is able to successfully connect to salesforce.com and obtain `authentication token`(indicated in bold in server log). However it is not able to reach the login page `https://login.salesforce.com`.

I am working from within a proxy server and have configured the same in my code. Still tomcat7 log is displaying following error:

```
Jun 11, 2013 5:56:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;E:\app\GreyMatter\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Sun\jwsdp-2.0\jwsdp-shared\bin;C:\Users\GreyMatter\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;E:\app\GreyMatter\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;E:\maven\apache-maven-3.0.4-bin_2\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;;E:\springsource-tool-suite\springsource\sts-2.9.2.RELEASE;;.
Jun 11, 2013 5:56:24 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:RestTest1' did not find a matching property.
Jun 11, 2013 5:56:24 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:RestTest' did not find a matching property.
Jun 11, 2013 5:56:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 11, 2013 5:56:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Jun 11, 2013 5:56:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 11, 2013 5:56:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 801 ms
Jun 11, 2013 5:56:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 11, 2013 5:56:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.8
Jun 11, 2013 5:56:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 11, 2013 5:56:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Jun 11, 2013 5:56:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 11, 2013 5:56:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 677 ms
**Auth successful - got callback**
Jun 11, 2013 5:57:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [oauth] in context with path [/RestTest] threw exception
java.net.UnknownHostException: login.salesforce.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at OAuthServlet.doGet(OAuthServlet.java:102)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The place where I have configured proxy settings is given below:

```
@WebServlet(name = "oauth", urlPatterns = { "/oauth/*", "/oauth" }, initParams = {
        // clientId is 'Consumer Key' in the Remote Access UI
        @WebInitParam(name = "clientId", value = "xxxx"),
        // clientSecret is 'Consumer Secret' in the Remote Access UI
        @WebInitParam(name = "clientSecret", value = "xxxxx"),
        // This must be identical to 'Callback URL' in the Remote Access UI
        @WebInitParam(name = "redirectUri", value = "https://localhost:8443/RestTest/oauth/_callback"),
        @WebInitParam(name = "environment", value = "https://login.salesforce.com") })
public class OAuthServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "ACCESS_TOKEN";
    private static final String INSTANCE_URL = "INSTANCE_URL";

    private String clientId = null;
    private String clientSecret = null;
    private String redirectUri = null;
    private String environment = null;
    private String authUrl = null;
    private String tokenUrl = null;

    public void init() throws ServletException {

        //****************************************************************
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "IP address of proxy server");
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "xxx");
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "Proxy login ID");
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "Proxy login password");

        System.getProperties().put("https.proxyHost", "IP address of proxy server");
        System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPort", "xxx");
        System.getProperties().put("https.proxyUser", "Proxy login ID");
        System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPassword", "Proxy login password");
        //**************************************************************


        clientId = this.getInitParameter("clientId");
        clientSecret = this.getInitParameter("clientSecret");
        redirectUri = this.getInitParameter("redirectUri");
        environment = this.getInitParameter("environment");
..... (rest of code)...
```

It seems that my java code is not able to connect to `https://login.salesforce.com`.
Is there any issue with proxy setting.
Kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: I hope that clientSecret and clientId wasn't the real parameters.

Comment: based on the staack trace I'd guess that the http client is not picking up the proxy settings, check that the http client stack you're using supports proxy config via those system properties.